# Show's an Warning How can i use ^

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitwise-operators, eslint

is

```
err^d === null
```

is same as

```
err === null && d === null
```

the both above condition outputs the same result when applied.

but eslint always show's

> unexpected use of '^' `no-bitwise`

Comment: What is the question here? If you have set *eslint*  to show warnings when you use bitwise operators it will do just that - see the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-bitwise) for more explanations. (Also I'm not convinced that `err^d` is really correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint by default prohibits bitwise operators, because they are normally a mistake (i.e. you meant `&&` but typed `&`). You can disable this behaviour by setting `no-bitwise` to `allow`. [See the documentation.](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-bitwise)

With that said, this won't do what you want. The bitwise operator coerces both the operands to numbers. This means that `null` is converted to `0`, as is `false`, `undefined`, the empty array, an array containing only `0`s, `NaN`, most (maybe all) objects. You aren't really testing for `null` here. [See the ECMAScript spec for demonstration of this.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10)

Comment: so `err^d` is converted to `0` and i am testing `0 === null` which returns `false`